# How to perform 'Tag Special' & 'Tag Assist' moves in Mortal Kombat (2011)?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

I have tried moves in both 'Fast Tags' and 'Tag Kombos' categories, the tutorial doesn't accept the moves (left corner with checkboxes):

[image]

---

Steam version.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing them exactly correctly?  I have personally logged a lot of hours into this game and have never had an issue doing tags in training. It could also be a bug, but I wouldn't assume that yet.

Comment: @Mumford451: Relatively sure, combo move starts after corresponding button presses. Do you mean that I should be able to finish both requirements by doing moves in fast tags and tag kombos categories?